# Pandas.read_excel reads date into timestamp, I want a string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, import-from-excel

I read a large Excel file into pandas using `.read_excel`, and the file has date columns. When read into pandas, the dates default to a timestamp. Since the file is large, I would like to read the dates as a string.

If that is not possible, then I would at least like to export the date back to Excel in the same format as it is in the original file (e.g. `"8/18/2009"`).

My two questions are:

1. Can I avoid converting the Excel date into a timestamp in pandas?
2. If not possible, how can I write back the date in the original format efficiently?

Comment: "When read into pandas the date defaults to a timestamp or, at least, when I export it back to Excel." Which of the two is it?

Comment: According to the comments in this question, there is no way to avoid converting Excel dates into timestamps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156830/leave-dates-as-strings-using-read-excel-function-from-pandas-in-python

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28769537/5276797

Comment: The code "f.write(vbscript.encode('utf-8'))" from the third comment doesn't work in python 3. I put it in the 2to3 converter and it didn't make changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It wasn't in binary, I changed "f = open('ExcelToCsv.vbs','w')" to "f = open('ExcelToCsv.vbs','wb')"

Comment: You could try to ask the author of the answer, by adding a comment to his answer. This is outside of my area of expertise unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that Excel doesn't store dates as strings, it stores them as numbers with a special format code.

Answer (score 3):

1. I am not sure how to read the date and not convert into timestamp using read_excel.
2. Because the date is already converted into datetime while reading it into a dataframe, here is how the date can be printed in the original format - I have used 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    "file_to_read.xlsx",
    sheet_name="sheetname",
)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
    "file_to_write.xlsx",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
    datetime_format="mm/dd/yyyy",
)
df.to_excel(
    writer,
    index=False,
    header=True,
    sheet_name="sheetname",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is similar as issue here. [Leave dates as strings using read_excel function from pandas in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156830/leave-dates-as-strings-using-read-excel-function-from-pandas-in-python/41117204#41117204)

check the answers:

- Using converters{'Date': str} option inside the pandas.read_excel which helps.
  `pandas.read_excel(xlsx, sheet, converters={'Date': str})`
- you can try convert your timestamp back to the original format
  `df['Date'][0].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
This is what solved the issue for me:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_link, sheet_name, dtype=str)
```

If you don't mind converting the df or entire column to string