# Pandas read excel with mixed date formats

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read Excel that has date values in one column. They are however in 2 different formats:

```
03.07.2017
03.07.2017
30/06/2017
30/06/2017
30/06/2017
03.07.2017
03.07.2017
```

07 and 06 are month numbers.

I import excel with:

```
denik=pd.read_excel('obchodnidenik.xlsx',converters={'Vstup - datum':str})
```

However the dates are converted differently.

I get two date formats that have switched dates/months:

```
'30/06/2017'
'2017-03-07 00:00:00'
```

What is the best way to convert all values into correct datetime?

Comment: Don't parse the dates while reading, replace `.` with `/` in strings, and then `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: But the parsing is automatic - I even tried to force "str" format, but it does not help.

Comment: Forcing converter type does work, are you doing it on right columns with right syntax https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117204?

Comment: U use syntax: denik=pd.read_excel('obchodnidenik.xlsx',converters={'Vstup - datum':str}) And the column 'Vstup - datum' is correct.

Comment: have you tried openpyxl? gives more flexibity of editing and importing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Series.replace` after reading the excel and then convert it into proper datetime and set `dayfirst = True` for proper months
example:

```
n = ['03.07.2017','03.07.2017','30/06/2017','30/06/2017','30/06/2017','03.07.2017','03.07.2017']
df = pd.DataFrame(n)
df[0]=df[0].replace('[/\/.]','-',regex=True)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0],dayfirst=True)
```

Output:

```
0   2017-07-03
1   2017-07-03
2   2017-06-30
3   2017-06-30
4   2017-06-30
5   2017-07-03
6   2017-07-03
```