# How I can stop python read_excel to convert date to datetime.. kindly help. Posting the same question again

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I read a large Excel file into pandas using [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), and the file has date columns. When read into pandas, the dates default to a timestamp. Since the file is large, I would like to read the dates as a string.

If that is not possible, then I would at least like to export the date back to Excel in the same format as it is in the original file (e.g. "8/18/2009").

My two questions are:

Can I avoid converting the Excel date into a timestamp in pandas?
If not possible, how can I write back the date in the original format efficiently?

Comment: paste your code here?

Comment: DF=pd.read_excel(path, dtype=str,na_filter=False)

I am using dtype = str because there are 100 of columns having leading 0s.

But due to this small chunk-

My input date :
03/29/2009

Getting changed to :
2009-03-29 00:00:00

The code is reading date as date timestamp

Comment: I'm not familiar with [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). However, according to its api, I think `parse_dates` and `date_parser` may the parameters you interest.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my question @ynjxsjmh but its still not working. I tried almost everything.

Comment: If the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/q/34156830/10315163 doesn't help and  pandas is silently converting the columns to datetime values. I think you can use the save-as function from Excel to save your excel as csv and use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to do your function. Or you could consider [bug reports](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#contributing-to-pandas-) to pandas.

Comment: Okay.. is there any way using which i can change format of all the date columns in the Data Frame?