# Pandas weirdly reading dates with read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem a little bit similar to [Leave dates as strings using read_excel function from pandas in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156830/leave-dates-as-strings-using-read-excel-function-from-pandas-in-python).

When doing:

```
x = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")
x = x[x["date"] > "2023-01-01"]
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

But when doing:

```
x = x[x["date"] > datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)]
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

So it seems that the column is neither 100% `str`, nor 100% `datetime` objects...

Indeed, some of them are strings like `18/12/2022` (arghh, unsortable with this format!), some of them are `datetime` objects.

TL;DR **How to make Pandas parse dates in a coherent way when opening a XLSX with `read_excel`?**

Comment: try to cast column 'date' to datetime dtype with x['date'] = pd.to_datetime(x['date'])

Comment: need example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: *Garbage in, garbage out*... The input file is likely to be the culprit with some cells containing true date values and others containing string values. You should first control which dtype `read_excel` gave to the column, then control the actual type of the cells. Without those informations it is hard to guess what should be done precisely.

Comment: What do you get out of `x["date"].map(type).value_counts()`?

Comment: @Learningisamess Indeed `date` `<class 'str'>                  406` `<class 'datetime.datetime'>      2`. I didn't know `value_counts()`, it's useful! You can post an answer this post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")
x = x[pd.to_datetime(x["date"], format='%d/%m/%Y') > '2023-01-01']
```

Comment: Shouldn't you compare to a datetime object instead of a string after casting it to a datetime series?

Comment: it works both ways

Answer (score 0):

Building on Kirill's answer:

```py
x = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")
x = x[pd.to_datetime(x["date"], format='%d/%m/%Y') > datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)]
```